# LaTeX, Can't color text

Tags: color

To be honest i don't know what the problem is, i just can't seem to get any of my text colored.

I made an example file to show you some demonstation of the problem:

```
     \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,dvips]{article}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[british]{babel}
     \usepackage{color}
     \usepackage{xcolor}

     \begin{document}

     \emph{some black text, {\color{red}followed 
      by a red fragment}, going black again.}
     \begin{itemize}
      \color{blue}
      \item Firts item
      \item Second item
       \end{itemize}

       \noindent
       {\color{red}}
       \textcolor{red}{easily}
       \end{document}`
```

This gives the following output:

```
            some black text, followed by a red fragment, going black again. 
            Firts item 
            Second item
            easily
```

As you can see, nothing has changed. Im running it with Quick Build in TexMaker(Have no ide if that makes a difference). And im not getting any errors.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I think the `\documentclass` option `dvips` is the culprit.  Also you don't need the `color` package as you are including the `xcolor` package.

Comment: @PeterGrill Didn't even notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's `dvipsnames`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,dvipsnames]{article}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[british]{babel}
     \usepackage{color}
     \usepackage{xcolor}

     \begin{document}

     \emph{some black text, {\color{red}followed
      by a red fragment}, going black again.}
     \begin{itemize}
      \color{blue}
      \item Firts item
      \item Second item
       \end{itemize}

       \noindent
       {\color{red}}
       \textcolor{red}{easily}
       \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: colors red and blue are basic colors and do not need the option `dvipsnames`

Comment: @herbert I know, I assumed `red` was only for the MWE while the OP is actually using a color which needs `dvipsnames` but spelled it wrongly. I know it's a lot to assume but, you know, it's free :)

Comment: @dcmst Thank's! Didn't even notice having it there. To much copy-paste.. Will mark it as a correct answer when i get the chance.

Comment: for an unknown color you'll get an error.

Comment: @Herbert I actually read that part of the question only now :o)

Answer (score 7):

Your `QuickBuild` uses `pdflatex` for the compilation of the text. But the option `dvips` means that you are using `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`. It is the wrong driver for `pdflatex`. Simply delete that option and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

If you can use pdflatex, the following simple modification does the work.

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,dvips]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage[british]{babel}
     \usepackage{color}
     \usepackage{xcolor}

     \begin{document}




     \emph{some black text, {\color{red}followed 
      by a red fragment}, going black again.}
     \begin{itemize}
      \color{blue}
      \item Firts item
      \item Second item
       \end{itemize}

       \noindent
       {\color{red}}
       \textcolor{red}{easily}
       \end{document}
```

[image]